# Performance issue with tensorflow version 1.5

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I have recently upgraded from tf 1.4 to 1.5. The process went through smoothly and everything seems to work as before. But I noticed that the training performance has dropped significantly, typically from 30% to 130%. Training time for my models increased from about 1 hour to more than two hours. The GPU load also dropped about 50%.

I am wondering what caused this performance reduction? How can I fix the problem. My system configuration is: windows 7; x64; AMD CPU; GTX-1070/8GB, python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed a significant decrease in performance with TF 1.5.0 on Windows 7 64bit, just tried it today.

Did upgrade to CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0. And I have Intel Xeon, Quadro K4000, Python 3.6.4

Will downgrade TF back to 1.4 and CUDA/cuDNN respectively, to make sure. If I find that it is faster again with the lower versions, I will start an Issue on TF github and reference this post.

---

**EDIT :**

I ended up testing all four of tensorflow 1.4.0, 1.5.0, -gpu 1.4.0, and -gpu 1.5.0 on a couple different networks I had been working on.

When I wrote my original response, the network I was working on was just a fairly simple RNN network. So I think it is known that GPU are actually *lower* performing than CPU for RNN networks! The hypothetical reason would be, and I think it makes sense, that RNN have far fewer components of the computations that can be parallelizeable. GPU are able to perform very fast because they contain a very high number of cores, which can compute in parallel. Indeed, when using OpenHardwareMonitor, the GPU core total load only got up to 60% peak on 1.4.0 and 52% peak on 1.5.0

So on that network, the computer's Xeon CPU actually does a pretty good job.

Interestingly, there still was a small slowdown going from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0, about 25% longer on the -gpu version and about 7% longer on the regular version.

But when I test on a different network that contained Convolutional operations, the GPU did perform significantly faster, AND 1.5.0 was faster than 1.4.0 in both -gpu and regular versions by around 10%.

So at the end of the day, I think it depends what type of network/operations you're working with, in deciding if -gpu version is best and if 1.4.0 or 1.5.0 is best.

Comment: Ya, I have actually removed TF 1.5 and re-installed TF 1.4 without downgrading CUDA & cuDNN; I got back the old performance. So, this problem is probably not caused by the new CUDA run-time.

Comment: @JamesLI how can tf-gpu 1.4.x run with cuda 9.0 and cudnn 7.0 ? I thought at the very least it was required that you used cuDNN64_6.dll . That is what it says on website https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows (even still, with 1.5.0 released) ? Did you just rename the .dll file?

Comment: Tensorflow seems to allow parallel installation of cuDNN 6 and 7, I was able to run TF 1.4 and 1.5 with both cuDNN 6 and 7 installed in a path directory, no rename or similar trick is needed.

Comment: @JamesLI interesting to note, because I have seen Issues on tensorflow Github where people could not use tf-gpu with wrong version of CUDA installed (supposed to be 8.0, but they installed 9.0, on tf-gpu 1.4). So you did have to switch down to CUDA 8.0 for tf-gpu 1.4, but could use either cuDNN64_6.dll or cuDNN64_7.dll ?

Comment: No, I didn't switch back to CUDA 8.0. I have upgraded CUDA from 8.0 to 9.0, then kept the configuration. I guess that the upgrade does not remove CUDA 8.0, the OS probably just keeps both 8.0 and 9.0.

Comment: @JamesLI yes correct the installs for CUDA 8.0 and 9.0 can coexist, and then I think it just depends on the CUDA_PATH (?)

Comment: Thanks for writing up your finds. It looks that TF 1.5 increased the CPU load for my test cases, so that CPU becomes a bottle-neck.